# How to apply cell background color using HSSF using Java code

Tags: java, excel, automation, apache-poi

I'm trying to format the cell background color based on the Testcase Execution status like if the test case got passed then the cell background should become **Green** and text color should be **White**.

Similarly for Failed test cases cell background color : **Red** and Text color : **White**

For that I tried the following script.

**Background:**

```
HSSFCellStyle style = wBook.createCellStyle()
style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex())
```

**Foreground:**

```
HSSFFont font = wBook.createFont()
font.setColor(HSSFColor.WHITE.index)
style.setFont(font)
resultCell.setCellStyle(style)
```

But after executing the test cases, cell background is not applying where as foreground only applies.

**FYI:** I'm Working with Excel version .XLS

Anyone give the correct method to apply background of the cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fiddling with the wrong. Excel's cell fills are pattern fills. There fill background color is the color behind the pattern and fill foreground color ist the color of the pattern.

So if setting `setFillBackgroundColor`, then you are setting the color behind the pattern which will only be visible if the pattern has gaps and is not solid.

Normally a cell is filled using `SOLID_FOREGROUND` pattern. So the color of the pattern is needed and not the color behind the pattern.

Try

```
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

Comment: Getting error message while executing the above lines thru Groovy script.. groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle.setFillPattern() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType) values: [SOLID_FOREGROUND] Possible solutions: setFillPattern(short), getFillPattern() error at line: 146

Comment: Answer POSTED for the above issue

Comment: @Karunagara: My code is working using the latest stable version of `apache poi`. Using this is really recommended. You should mentione in the question that you are using an ancient version of `apache poi` and which. So such misunderstandigs could be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for the below lines:

```
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex())
style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND)
```