# Apache POI returns same backgroundcolor even if there are different backgroundcolors for different cells

Tags: java, apache-poi

Apache POI returns same backgroundcolor even if there are different backgroundcolors for different cells

getFillBackgroundColorColor() (or) getFillBackgroundXSSFColor returns same color

eventhough there are different background colors in different cells

Comment: Please add code as well.

Comment: You needs to know how Excel fills cells interior. There is pattern filling always. There `FillBackgroundColor...` is the color behind the pattern while `FillForegroundColor...` is the color of the pattern. And default interior filling is using `SOLID_FOREGROUND`  pattern. So what you see in Excel is `FillForegroundColor...`, the color of the solid pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply cell background color using HSSF using Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48741135/how-to-apply-cell-background-color-using-hssf-using-java-code)

Comment: XSSFCell celllocal = row1.getCell(j);
XSSFCellStyle cs = celllocal.getCellStyle();
System.out.println("getFillBackgroundColor color f1 : "+cs.getFillBackgroundColor());
       if(cs.getFillBackgroundColorColor()!=null)  
       System.out.println("getFillBackgroundColorColor color f2: "+cs.getFillBackgroundColorColor());
       if(cs.getFillBackgroundXSSFColor()!=null)  
       System.out.println("font getFillBackgroundColorColor f3 : "+cs.getFillBackgroundXSSFColor());

Comment: Please **edit** your question, do not add information in the comments.