# How to add background color in excel sheet by Apache poi <=3.17 version

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I have an excel sheet where i am merging the columns and making it a single column on a row and trying to add the background color but its not working.

```
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
Font font = workbook.createFont();
font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)12);
font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
cellStyle.setBorderTop((short) 2); // single line border
cellStyle.setBorderBottom((short) 2); // single line border
cellStyle.setFont(font);
cellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_CORNFLOWER_BLUE.getIndex());
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48741135/how-to-apply-cell-background-color-using-hssf-using-java-code/48742978#48742978

Comment: thanks for reply also if i have add custom color for the same background .what i need to do any pointer ?

Comment: "add custom color": Not to answer in that general. For `XSSF` it is simply [setFillForegroundColor(XSSFColor color)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setFillForegroundColor-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor-). For `HSSF` you would need overwriting one of the predefined colors. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117806/adding-custom-colours-to-excel-sheet-using-apche-poi/53120147#53120147.